# matching both possible rel values in a <link>

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm currently parsing for webmention endpoints with the following code. This works for either `<link rel="webmention" href=" ">` or `<link rel="http://webmention.org/" href=" ">` but not if both are included, i.e. `<link rel="webmention http://webmention.org/" href=" ">`. And I'm struggling to adapt it to that. The code currently:

```
if(preg_match('/<(?:link|a)[ ]+href="([^"]+)"[ ]+rel="webmention"[ ]*\/?>/i', $body, $match)
  || preg_match('/<(?:link|a)[ ]+rel="webmention"[ ]+href="([^"]+)"[ ]*\/?>/i', $body, $match)) {
    $endpoint = $match[1];
} elseif(preg_match('/<(?:link|a)[ ]+href="([^"]+)"[ ]+rel="http:\/\/webmention\.org\/?"[ ]*\/?>/i', $body, $match)
  || preg_match('/<(?:link|a)[ ]+rel="http:\/\/webmention\.org\/?"[ ]+href="([^"]+)"[ ]*\/?>/i', $body, $match)) {
    $endpoint = $match[1];
}
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php for html manipulation

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this piece, see if you find it useful

```
'/\<link.+?rel=["']?(?:webmention|http\:\/\/webmention\.org\/?)['"]?.*?\>/g'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tE8gZ0/2)

P.S.: A word of advice - You use regular expressions like they are nothing. Regular expressions should be used only if there is no other way, especially if `$body` is a large string, you should really not run so many `preg_match`es on it. Cheers!

Comment: It was code I'd inhereited from another project, based on the other comment I'm trying DOMDocument, which seems to work:

Comment: @JonnyBarnes I think it would be highly inefficient to parse a whole html document into PHP objects in order to pick up one `DOM` element, but that is just my opinion.